# subscript and superscript for the same element

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Is there any way to add both subscript and and superscript to the same element? If I do

```
Sample Text<sub>Sub</sub><sup>Sup</sup>
```

the superscript appears after the subscript. One I idea I had is to do something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' valign='center'>Sample Text</td>
        <td>Sup</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It seems to do the job but is quite ugly. Any better ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I'd hazard a guess that you should be looking at MathML, but your example has been abstracted too far to tell.

Comment: It's just some data I want displayed in a specific way. Nothing special like math, physics, chemistry...etc. I checked MathML but it's not supported natively by IE and that's means I can't use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm no CSS guru but you could try something along the lines of http://jsfiddle.net/TKxv8/1/

There are a lot of hardcoded values and the effects on other elements around may only be found afterwards but it's a good place to start.

```
Sample Text 
<span class='supsub'>
    <sup class='superscript'>Sup</sup>
    <sub class='subscript'>Sub</sub>
</span>

.supsub {position: absolute}
.subscript {color: green; display:block; position:relative; left:2px; top: -5px}
.superscript {color: red; display:block; position:relative; left:2px; top: -5px}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! You may want to include your code here, in case anyone has the same problem, as the jsfiddle version may get deleted.

Comment: .supsub {position: absolute}

.subscript {color: green; display:block; position:relative; left:2px; top: -5px}

.superscript {color: red; display:block; position:relative; left:2px; top: -5px}


Sample Text <span class='supsub'><sup class='superscript'>Sup</sup><sub class='subscript'>Sub</sub></span>

Comment: sorry about the formatting - not working in comments and I'd not add a new answer

Comment: If you're looking at this now, do check out Thomas' answer below. It accounts for the subscript and superscript in the proceeding text. IMHO its the best solution :)

Answer (score 17):

This one is similar to CyberDudes approach, additionally it indents the following text depending on the width of sub and sup:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwFec/1/

```
Some text <span class="supsub"><sup>sup</sup><sub>sub</sub></span> followed by other text.<br />

<style>
.supsub {
    display: inline-block;
}

.supsub sup,
.supsub sub {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: .5em;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.supsub sub {
    top: .3em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Should be the preferred solution as it allows fall back to standard html and therefore more inline with structure for readers.

Comment: As an additional note, from a layout perspective, I found it better to set the line height t0 0.9em and not bother with the final .supsub sub{top.... less overlap.  I mention for ref if someone encounters same issue though may be stylesheet dependant.

Answer (score 8):

I use the following:

```
.supsub {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<span class="supsub">
    <span>sup</span>
    <span>sub</span>
</span>
```

Comment: This works really well if you set the font-size for `.supsub` to 50%

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can specify position of `sup` relative to `Sample Text`'s right border.

http://jsfiddle.net/a754h/

Comment: Not very selectableable. MathML would be better, though it's not widely supported.

Comment: Ben, may I ask what do you mean by "not very selectableable"? You mean if someone wants to copy/paste the data?

Comment: seems to fail (relative to expectation) when the sup is longer than the sub, and the text continues afterwards.  in this example, the width is determined by the sub.  the super just positions, but does not expand the bounding box.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a clean solution. Create two CSS classes:

```
.nobr {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
.supsub {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: -9em 0;
   vertical-align: -0.55em;
   line-height: 1.35em;
   font-size: 70%;
   text-align: left;
}
```

You might already have the "nobr" class as a <nobr> replacement. Now to express the molecular formula for sulfate, use the "supsub" class as follows:

```
<span class="nobr">SO<span class="supsub">2-<br />4</span></span>
```

That is, enclose your superscript/subscript within the "supsub" class, and put a <br /> between them. If you like your superscripts/subscripts a bit larger or smaller, then adjust the font size and then tinker with the vertical-align and line-height. The -9em in the margin setting is to keep the superscripts/subscripts from adding to the height of the line containing them; any big value will do.

Answer (score 1):

On addition to the solution of CyberDude here there is a example that you can do using sup and sub tags and css with flexbox.

```html
<div class="expression">
Sample Text 
<span class='supsub'>
  <sup class='superscript'>Sup</sup>
  <sub class='subscript'>Sub</sub>
</span>
</div>
```

```css
.expression {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.supsub {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.subscript {
  color: green; 
  display:flex;
}

.superscript {
  color: red; 
  display:flex; 
}
```

You can see and test this here [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gudermw/#&togetherjs=Umk2Dje6Qn)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done very simply by using inline style as well. Specifically:  `style='position: relative; left: -0.4em;'`

So an example would be: `u<sub>i</sub><sup style='position: relative; left: -0.4em;'>T</sup>`

One can vary the position by changing the value after left. It doesn't reproduce here, but it works fine otherwise.