# Subscript and superscript alignment using only HTML markup

Tags: html, latex, html4

The following picture can be easily produced using a latex rendering software:

[image: Tensors, from Wikipedia!]

In particular superscript and subscript parts are one over the other.

Is it possibile getting the same result using only HTML 4 syntax by some clever use of `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags, without use of CSS or MathML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have sub- and superscript for an element at the same time using only HTML.

However, using CSS, there are solutions. For inspiration, have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742975/subscript-and-superscript-for-the-same-element).

**Edit:** [Source.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sub)

> **`<sub>`**
>
> The *HTML Subscript Element* (`<sub>`) defines a span of text that should be displayed, for typographic reasons, lower, and often smaller, than the main span of text.
>
> [...]
>
> The `<sup>` HTML element that produces superscript. Note that you cannot
>   use them both at the same time and you need to use MathML to produce
>   both a superscript and a subscript next to the chemical symbol of an
>   element, representing its atomic number and its nuclear number.

Also note the following remark about `<sub>` from the same page:

> This element should be used for typographical reasons only, i.e.
>   changing the position of the text changing its meaning like in
>   mathematical (like t2, though the use of a MathML formula should be
>   considered) or chemical formulas (like H2O).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You followed the standards and that's good, but a "non-standard" solution was also good for me.

Comment: @Blex Well, it is not possible without using CSS, not only in the standard. The accepted answer does use CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way(not the best but yes this works):

```
a<sup>2</sup><sub style='position: relative; left: -.5em;'>i</sub>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a754h/130/)**

Just to add that this does not mean that you can use the subscript and superscript at the same time. Its just an illusion which is created by using the style tag. This will change and is not reliable across browsers.

Comment: It actually seems like a hack, but it's I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could get it with as few as one argument in the `style` attribute, although **inline styles shouldn't be used anymore**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sub and sup inline</title>
</head>

<body>
T<sup>j<sub>1</sub>,...,j<sub>h</sub></sup><sub 
 style="margin-left:-35px">i<sub>1</sub>,...,i<sub>k</sub></sub>
</body>
</html>
```

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jc4t7mn/)). Instead, if you can use the `style` tag in the `head` and a `class` in the `body` (that is recommended), you get the same output as above this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sub and sup class</title>
<style>.fixmargin{margin-left:-35px}</style>
</head>

<body>
T<sup>j<sub>1</sub>,...,j<sub>h</sub></sup><sub 
 class="fixmargin">i<sub>1</sub>,...,i<sub>k</sub></sub>
</body>
</html>
```

Better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sub and sup span</title>
</head>

<body>
T<span style="position:relative">
<span style="position:absolute;left:2px;top:-9px">j<sub>1</sub>,...,j<sub>h</sub></span>
<span style="position:absolute;left:2px;top:8px">i<sub>1</sub>,...,i<sub>k</sub></span>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

but, again, this can (and should) be achieved with the `style` tag in the `head` and three `class` attributes in the `span`s.